# How to get a web page source code with GeckoView

Tags: java, android, geckoview

I am an android developer and I knew about [GeckoView](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/) recently.
I can get source code of a web page by android WebView (java code).

However with my new website, android Webview can't load the webpage but GeckoView can.
Now I want to get source code of a web page by GeckoView.
Is there any body know the solution to resolve this problem ?

Thank in advance

Comment: Do you want to get source code of page as string?

Comment: @NatigBabayev: Yes. I do

Comment: Do you use Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I use java for getting source code with android WebView

Comment: Why do you want to get the source code? What are you tryig to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use GeckoView to get the source code, but the geckoview library does have [GeckoWebExecutor](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoWebExecutor.html). Take a look at the fetch method and the [WebResponse](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/WebResponse.html) it returns.

By converting the `WebResponse.body` InputStream to a String you can get the source code.

Answer (score 0):

One option for doing this could follow these steps:

1. detect which page my geckoview loaded;
2. save the loaded url into a sharedpref;
3. if user wants to see the source of the page, load the url saved within that sharedpref.

So...

**(1-2)** as you already know, geckoview doesn't have that handy `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method, so you will have to deal with the `NavigationDelegate` class, which has the `onLocationChange()`, where i put this line, which does nothing more than save the current url as a string into a sharedpref string named "geckoViewUrl":

> sharedprefs.edit().putString("geckoViewUrl", url).apply();

having all setup before (sharedprefs etc). Detected the loaded page and saved the url into a sharedpref, let's go to the final step 3.

**(3)** for my use, wishing only to allow the user to see (and copy) the source, for the law of the minimum effort i used another activity with a plain and old webview to display it. This is very easy to implement and rises no confusion to the user. He/She wants to see the code, i show it in another activity. When it's done, he/she closes the new activity and life continues.

So, user wants source? Load another activity with a webview and make it load that saved sharedpref string:

> addr2open = pref_out.getString("geckoViewUrl", "");

Doing this (for example), you get the url user wants to see source assigned to a string var. To finish, all you have to do is to make the webview load this string preceded by the precious word `view-source:`, this way:

> webView.loadUrl("view-source:" + addr2open);

That's it. Of course you could implement a solution relying on the same activity, or using geckoView, showing multiple options, menus etc. I only wanted to show you a way to solve your problem in a nice 'n' easy way. You asked for "How to get a web page source code with GeckoView". Here is the answer. Works perfectly. If this is good for you, please, accept this as the correct answer. Thank you. Happy coding.

One example on the use of "view-source", from the creators of GeckoView: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/view_source/index.html (see item "Link to a line number").